# Org shape doesn't copy Healthcloud, nor PersonAccount setup

Tags: salesforcedx, org-shape

I'm creating a new scratch org using Org Shape and `sfdx`, from an org that has PersonAccounts enabled, as well as HealthCloud installed. I'm trying to deploy my metdata. I get errors such as:

> No such column 'IsPersonAccount' on entity 'Account'

And

> Invalid type: HealthCloudGA__EhrEncounter__c

It doesn't seem like Org Shape is copying the actual org shape. It also seems like at least one installed managed package is also not present in the new scratch org.

Does Org Shape actually do anything, or does it discard all the useful information from the org?

Comment: It is expected that Org shape will not copy Managed Package. It only just includes features, Metadata API settings, edition, limits, and licenses

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Shouldn't it copy in the PersonAccount setting?